# How to store users that signed up with facebook?

Tags: php, laravel-5, facebook-login

I added "Signup/Signin with Facebook" buttons to my website using Socialite on laravel 5.4.
When a user signs up with facebook, i get his e-mail address and use it to create a new entry in my users' table.

Everything seemed to work great, until someone signed up with a facebook account that did not provide the e-mail address. ( I guess he signed up on facebook using his phone number).
So, in this case, i get a "null" from the e-mail field on the facebook response...

Well, i thought of using the facebook id as a new field in the table for facebook signups instead of using the e-mail.
But i don't know if that would do it...
If not, what would be a solution please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You should use `facebook id`, because facebooks users may change their `email` and `phone number`, but `facebook id` will remain until they remove their account and create new one )))

Answer (score 1):

facebook ID is a unique identifier for each user you can use it instead of email address as you mentioned not all users have to sign up with email address.
FB ID will do it don't worry, i used it dozens of times.